# Consider the function $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2+3).$ Compute the partial derivatives of the first and second order.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'have been trying to calculate the last partial derivative but did not get the correct answer. My teacher's answer is $-4xy/(x^2+y^2+3)^2$. Can you please explain how we got it? (with a solution) I've been trying using the general quotient rule and the output was a total mess. My exam is in 5 hours :)

Thanks! [image]

Comment: Take your answer for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and differentiate with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ is the same as 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+3}\\
=2y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+3}=2y\frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2+3)^2}\\
=\frac{-4xy}{(x^2+y^2+3)^2}\\
$$
by the quotient rule and noting that $y$ is constant when we take the partial in $x$.

Comment: thank you very much. What I've been trying to do before was differentiating fyy even further by the quotient rule.

Comment: yeah definitely don't do that if you are trying to find $f_{xy}$.